# processing multiple word.docx files from a folder to csv

Tags: python-3.x

I need to create multiple df.csv files from multiple docx. files from a folder.
I've managed to open a single file then extract a "word table" and exporting to csv with the following code:

```
entrega = Document("mypath/.../30 enero.docx")
data = [[cell.text for cell in row.cells] for row in entrega.tables[0].rows]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('destination _path/.../Enero 30.csv')
```

creating df.csv i can easily work with the data. So my problem now is that i need to do it with a list of about 300 files, for example the list of january 22' is

```
import os
Path = "/Users/cristobalmino/Desktop/3_ENTREGA DE TURNOS MEDICA/Entrega Turno UCI/2022/1. Enero 2022/"
filelist = os.listdir(Path)
filelist
```

```
['26 enero2.docx',
 '11 enero.docx',
.
.
.
.
 '03 enero.docx']
```

Is there a way i can do a function to avoid manually enter every file and extract this dataframe creating csv files?

Answer (score 0):

Use **FOR** loop:

```
import os

path = '/Users/cristobalmino/Desktop/3_ENTREGA DE TURNOS MEDICA/Entrega Turno UCI/2022/1. Enero 2022/'
   
for doc_file_name in os.listdir(path):
    docx_file_path = os.path.join(path, doc_file_name )

    entrega = Document(docx_file_path)
    data = [[cell.text for cell in row.cells] for row in entrega.tables[0].rows]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_csv(f"{doc_file_name.replace('docx', 'csv')}")
```